# parse char array and don't delete delimiter c++

Tags: c++

I have the next code:

```
    char str[] = "%fds%f%dssa%sss";
    char* tokenStr = strtok(buffer, "%");
    while (tokenStr != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << tokenStr << '\n';
        tokenStr = strtok(NULL, "%");
    }
```

Output:

```
fds
f
dssa
sss
```

but I don't need to delete %.
Expected output:

```
    %fds
    %f
    %dssa
    %sss
```

I reckon using function `strpbrk` is bad idea, because it will be difficult to realize on controller. Thanks

Comment: cout << "%" << tokenStr << '\n'; ??

Comment: [std::regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) will provide arbitrary non-destructive iteration over both matched and unmatched content, if your needs are more complex than this trivial example.

Comment: I will safe message like "%fds" to other variable

Comment: std::regex_token_iterator is good, but I cannot connect #include <regex> to my project in my controller.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also cannot use namespace std, and string

Comment: Why are you using `std::cout` then?  That is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Maybe just parse the values yourself.  It's a simple loop.  Since you want to store these values elsewhere, you basically have three choices: (1) terminate the strings and store pointers into the original; (2) don't terminate the strings, store pointers into the original and use logic that either stores the length or understands `%` as a delimiter when outputting; (3) copy the strings, in which case it doesn't matter if you choose to modify the original or not.

Comment: @paddy std needs only for test

Comment: This question will probably end up being closed because it lacks sufficient detail to provide a properly engineered answer.  You must specify exactly how these values are going to be stored and why you can't modify the original.  Also specify why, if everything will be prefixed by `%`, you can't build that into your program as an assumption / ground truth (see very first comment) when storing / outputting values.  Generally, when questions are asked with severe technological limitations imposed (_e.g._ can't use anything in `std`) they are poorly-specified questions and usually homework.

Comment: there was an idea using a function 'strcpy' to save to another variable and add % to position [0]

Comment: That is essentially what I mentioned as option #3, except in that case it's pointless to use `strtok` at all.

Comment: @Andrei There are lots of ways to do this, but strtok is not one of them as it destroys the delimiter *by design*. Since you are not allowed to use higher level features you're stuck with some low level programming. If the only C++ feature you are allowed to use is `std::cout` then you really must ask yourself what language you are learning (and this question would probably be better tagged as C not C++).

Comment: @paddy constraints due to the fact that I am writing a program to the Pixhawk controller, there is no STD and no standard library. https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/style-guide.html#no-standard-library

Comment: Yeah, I get it...  If you haven't been able to learn from the rest of my guidance here that IS relevant, then I don't think anyone can help you.  Unless they actually write the code for you, which I would argue doesn't really help.  Read my comments carefully.  In there, you'll find various approaches that will work perfectly for whatever your final requirement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to go with regexes (may be overkill here), the pair `strspn`, `strcspn` from the C standard library (which **is** a subset of the C++ standard library) should be enough:

```
char str[] = "%fds%f%dssa%sss";
char *first, *last;
for(first=str;;) {
    last = first + strcspn(first, "%");
    if (first != str) {     // special processing for first char of string
        first -= 1;
    }
    if (last != first) {
        std::cout << std::string(first, last) << '\n';
    }
    if (*last == '\0') break;
    first = last + 1;
}
```

It should process the string whether it starts or not with a `%` character.

---

If you do not want to use a `std::string` you can output one character at a time:

```
    if (last != first) {
        while (first < last) std::cout << *first++;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: can you explain how I can change you row `std::cout << std::string(first, last) << '\n';` for using without `std::string()`?

Comment: @Andrei: you can always process one character at a time... (just see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

using [regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
 
int main()
{
    std::string input("%fds%f%dssa%sss");
    std::regex r("^%+[\\w]+");
    std::smatch sm;
    while(regex_search(input, sm, r))
    {
        std::cout << sm.str() << '\n';
        input = sm.suffix();
        
    }
    
}
```

output:

```
%fds    
%f    
%dssa    
%sss
```